# logstah vs spark streaming and storm

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, logstash, apache-storm, spark-streaming

I am working on building a distributed real time cluster system to supervise and analyze a network. I did several researches on internet and I came out with few technologies:

- for real time processing : logstash, storm and apache streaming
- for storage: elasticsearch
- for analysis: Apache Spark over Hadoop (I will use ES-Hadoop to connect with Elasticsearch)
- for data visualization: kibana, D3js, c3js

However, logstash is not often mentioned as spark streaming and storm. I found in internet the following architecture presented in the below picture:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. I don't understand why logstash is not often mentioned as a real-tim processing system like spark streaming and storm. What are the main reasons ? I hav been using it and it is very powerful..
2. Regarding the Analyze part, can I use the machine learning librairies in that configuration ?

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear but what I am asking is what might be the main reasons not to choose logstash with respect to spark streaming and storm ? It is very difficult for me to answer to this question since I don't find any comparison in internet.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Logstash is not cluster stream processing system. It is simply a JVM based process. The latest version supports on disk buffer but does not have the nearly the same delivery guaranties as Spark or Storm. Take a look at http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.3/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html
2. Yes but not sure why use Elastic for storing data first. Why not HDFS->SparkML->Elastic? The main thing to think here is managing models, training and testing.